# Enlarge images with close or X button

Tags: android, eclipse, popup

I have a horizontal scrollable gallery view.. What I want is when I click on a particular image, it pops up to center with the close button. (Like Enlargement of an image)

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this?

Reference : [Gallery View](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-3-more-views)

If the horizontalView is as displayed then you can have an ImageView and display it there. Just a few lines of code will set it up. Follow the tutorial worked for me!